# Multiple table search Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been having some issues with searching multiple tables in my rails app, and I am unsure of the best method to approach this.

I have two tables: Trial (has_many :results) and Result (belongs_to :trial). I want to create a search form that hits these two tables and grabs the relevant results.

I want to compare data from 'variety_one' against 'variety_two' in my form based on years, irrigated (0,1,2 integer) and regions and list in a 3 column table. First column being 'Variety One' second 'Varety Two' and the third being the difference between the two previous. I.e.

Result has columns: variety_id (relating to :variety_one and :variety_two params), years
Trial has columns: region_id, irrigated

```
       | Variety One | Variety Two | Different
Yield  |   5.00      |    4.00     |  1.00
length |   1.00      |    0.50     |  0.50
```

My View

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: vpc_search_path do |f| %>
<%= f.select :variety_one, @variety.collect {|v| [v.variety_name, v.variety_id]}, :selected => '2300', :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.select :variety_two, @variety.collect {|v| [v.variety_name, v.variety_id]}, :selected => '2308', :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.input :irrigated, collection: @irrigations, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
<%= f.input :years, collection: @years, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
<%= f.input :regions, collection: @regions, as: :check_boxes, :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My Controller

```
class VpcController < ApplicationController
  def index
    all = Result.select(:variety_id)
    @variety = Variety.where(:variety_id => all).order('variety_name DESC')
    @years = Result.select('DISTINCT year').pluck(:year)
    @regions = Trial.select('DISTINCT region_id').pluck(:region_id)
    @irrigations = Trial.select('DISTINCT irrigated').pluck(:irrigated)
  end

  def search
   @result = Result.search(params[:search])
   @trial = Trial.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

Search View

```
<table class="table">
        <th></th>
    <th>Variety One</th>
    <th>Variety Two</th>
    <th>Difference</th>
<tr>
<td>Yield (bales/ha)</td>
<% @result.each do |v| %>
<td><%= "%.2f" % (v.lint) %></td>
<td><%= v.length %></td>
<td><%= ?? %></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement Result.search and Trial.search methods, or are you hitting a problem with the above code? It might help to show us your search results view as well.

Comment: Asking how best to tackle the problem. I'll add my search view above. I have a loop and I guess the main issue I have is the loop as I have two tables to grab data from.

Comment: You had me up until the beginning of your third paragraph, where you begin talking about variety one and variety two. I think it might be helpful to see the structure of your `trials` and `results` table. Can you post that too please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In general, for tables you want to display one row for each iteration through the loop, so your opening tr element would go just after the @result.each line, and the closing tr just above the end.

The real difficulty seems to be keeping the results and trials together. Would it be possible to create maybe an array of hashes, with each hash two keys: 'result' and 'trial'? Then you would iterate over that array, and get the values out of each hash. But there's not enough information here to know if that's a workable approach. The question is that if @result contains a bunch of results and @trial contains a bunch of trials, how do you tell which goes with which?

I also see a real danger of embedding too much logic and calculations in the view itself. You probably want to consider the presenter pattern, either making your own presenter object or using a gem like draper. That way in the view you can just declare what each thing is, and keep the details of its calculation in the preenter class.